# groovy singleton to access overloaded constructor

Tags: groovy

groovy Singleton (NB at Groovy 2.6 you must set strict to false if you want to include the explicit constructor)

```
@Singleton( strict = false )
class test {

    private test(){
        //some Method call      
    }

    private test(def x){
        //some Method call
    }
}
```

test.groovy

```
def test1 = test.instance
```

when i issue the following statement it works for me and i can see the defualt 
constructor is called

how can i create instanace while using second construcor argument

if i issue

```
def test2 = test("anish").instance
```

it throws me error how do i resolve this any suggestion

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: test.test() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [anish]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
```

Comment: Please include the error. I'd have to look at the actual transformation, but I'm not sure it'll work with non-default ctors.

Comment: Dude! Why use a pattern if you don't understand its purpose? The whole point of declaring a class singleton is restricting it to have only one instance

Answer (score 6):

In the first case you are accessing the static property `test.instance`, which in turn calls the static method `test.getInstance()`.  In the second case, it looks like you are trying to call the second constructor as a method.  That's not valid groovy: you need to use the `new` keyword to create an instance, which triggers the constructor.  Also, making the constructor private makes it inaccessible except within the class itself.

If you need to instantiate another instance, it probably shouldn't be a singleton in the first place.

Comment: + 1 esp for the last sentence